# Django: CSS file won't update

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms

I'm having some issues changing Django Form's CSS. Here is my code
(Template):

```
<form method="post" action="."  id="signup">
    <div class="container">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit" value="{% trans 'Submit' %}">Join</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Model:

```
class ExRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    age = forms.IntegerField()
    location = forms.CharField()
    phone = forms.CharField()
```

Model:

```
class ExUserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default = 19)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=2, default = "location")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, default = "phone number")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user


def user_registered_callback(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    profile = ExUserProfile(user = user)
    profile.age = request.POST["age"]
    profile.location = request.POST["location"]
    profile.phone = request.POST["phone"]
    profile.save()
```

CSS:

```
.container input[type=text], .container input[type=password], .container input[type=email], .container input[type=number] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
  margin: 0.3em 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0.1em solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
```

Result:

[image]

The style for my email and number field is not updating, I thought the issue might be related to Django forms auto generating the fields and doing something weird, but from inspect, it shows that the fields have normal names and input types. So nothing is out of the ordinary except the fact that the CSS isn't being update.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you look in the browser dev tools, or just view source, and see?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The title of the question is a bit confusing, I will edit that. The question is, why isn't the css for those two input types being implemented ? I don't know what the issue is, I even tried creating CSS for the field's id, for example django form sets the id for email as "id_email", I created a specific css for that id and it still did not change anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue was related to the fact that my browser had cached my old CSS file, therefore wouldn't show any updates. It was hard for me to solve the issue because I didn't really understand the problem.

The solution was quiet simple:

> Ctrl + Shift + Del

In Chrome, you can use the above command to delete the cache, therefore allowing for the new static files to load.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you got the CSS selector right? Go to inspect element, select your element and click copy selector. That will give you an insight about the Css selector of your input elements.

Comment: I have used google chrome's inspect and I can see what is being applied and where, I can read the ID and input type etc.. Examining the password input, it clearly show the css being used, but these two labels are missing from the css .container input[type=email], .container input[type=number]. This means my css file hasn't been implemented in full?? or those two labels defining the number and email input fields are excluded for some reason..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quotes in css selector: e.g. input[type="text"]

Comment: I don't think you do,

Answer (score 0):

Django will not serve static content (i.e. CSS changes) when Debug is False.

Ensure Debug=True in your settings.py file